# How can I follow tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

How can I follow tags on Stack Overflow (so that the next time I log in, I can directly find my favorite questions from the main page)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flag your favorite questions by clicking on the star between the question score and the icons to share on G+ / Facebook.

Later you can retrieve these favorites on your profile, in the "Favorites" tab.

Answer (score 0):

The site's sidebar has a "Favorite tags" field right at the top. You can add your favorite tags there, and the front page should start showing you relevant questions.

There is also an "ignored tags" field. Add tags there to exclude them from your front page.